# How does Data Encapsulation actually happen in OOP?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm learning C++.

Came across data encapsulation and data hiding at a website, check out the following piece of code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class sum {
private: int a, b, c;

public:
    void add() {
        clrscr();
        cout << "Enter any two numbers: ";
        cin >> a >> b;
        c = a + b;
        cout << "Sum: " << c;
    }
};
void main() {
    sum s;
    s.add();
    getch();
}
```

NOW. As it says [here](https://www.sitesbay.com/cpp/cpp-encapsulation) that:

The main advantage of using of encapsulation is to secure the data from other methods, when we make a data private then these data only use within the class, but these data not accessible outside the class.

What happens underneath the code, what does the compiler do that makes it inaccessible to other classes? And in the given example what was the reason behind defining `a`,`b` and `c` as private.

What were they trying to achieve by hiding "just the declarations of the three variables"? Because anyone can see that inside public three numbers being used are `a`,`b`, and `c` - first two for input and third one for output.

Comment: "*How is this possible that the data under private can't be accessed outside the class?*" Because *that's what `private` means*.

Comment: You can't access it via `s.c` for example.

Comment: Your example is nonsensical.  There is no reason to have private data members in `sum`, so it doesn't illustrate encapsulation well.

Comment: No actually the example was on the website

Comment: Ah, I see now. Didn't spot the link on the first read. Then ditch that website. If this is how it "teaches" encapsulation, stay clear of it, like you would a forest fire.

Comment: `what were they trying to achieve by hiding "just the declarations of the three variables"?` generally one of the more common reasons for information hiding is to seperate the specific implementation from the public interface. In this case for example you might not want other people using your class to depend on the fact that it calculates using ints. By making those data members private you are free to change the class for example later to use floats (or a BigNumber class) and you would be sure that nobody directly relied on the fact that you stored the intermediate products as ints.

Comment: Wow I got a lot of downvotes; maybe my modified question would come forth as a valid one? If not then I gotta stop asking my petty doubts here

Comment: `include<iostream.h>` don’t try to learn C++ with a compiler from the stone age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is this possible that the data under private can't be accessed
>   outside the class?

Compiler makes sure you don't. If you try to access say `a` outside class, your code will not compile.

> And in the given example what was the reason behind defining a,b and c
>   as private.

It could be anything! But as a result, a,b and c are not accessible outside members of class.

Basically you want to **hide** some variables in your class for the sake of consistency. So that you or your clients can not produce a code that makes unwanted and uncontrolled changes.

**Updates:**

> What happens underneath the code, what does the compiler do that makes
>   it unaccessible to other classes?

Compiler implementation check for access level while producing code. If there is something wrong, you will get a syntax error and no machine code will be generated from your file.

> And in the given example what was the reason behind defining a,b and c
>   as private; what were they trying to achieve by hiding "just the
>   declarations of the three variables"? Because anyone can see that
>   inside public three numbers being used are a,b, and c - first two for
>   input and third one for output.

You don't hide variables in your class to make them invisible to others. Private variables that are not intended to be used from outside of the class can be marked as `private` to limit the potential for coding errors.

As an example consider following class:

```
class rectangle {
  public:
    int width;
    int height;
    int area;
};

void something_important(const rectangle& r) {
// ... 
}
```

What happens if I pass a rectangle of width -10, height 0 and area of -15? There could be a plane crash or a nuclear weapon launched to some wrong target... So I will make sure my rectangles are always valid:

```
class rectangle {
  public:
    void set_width(int w) {
      if(w) width = w;
      else width = 0;
      area = width*height;
    }
    int get_width() const {return width;}
    void set_height(int h) {
      if(w) height = h;
      else height = 0;
      area = width*height;
    }
    int get_height() const {return height;}
    int get_area() const {return area;}
  private:
    int width;
    int height;
    int area;
};
```

So no one can make a rectangle of negative height or width, and no one can make a rectangle having a wrong area. (you can not actually change area directly)

I hope it makes sense for you now.

Comment: Yes but the client could as well have a look at the public section and see that the variables being used are a,b and c and then use them to his purpose by changing stuff inside public?

Comment: (: If they change your work, they are not using your work anymore. The key point here is not secrecy but consistency and error preventation.

Comment: Oh, you updated your question... So will do my answer

Comment: Painstakingly and brilliantly answered! Thanks

Comment: Encapsulation does much more than "data integrity" for the code you're writing today. By preventing the clients from directly accessing the data here, you're limiting how the client can interact with the class (preventing cohesion). This allows you to completely reimplement the details without breaking the client (e.g., you don't have to have data integrity first; you can add that later. Or, you can remove "width" and calculate that on the fly, without breaking the scores of users.)

Answer (score 3):

> What happens underneath the code, what does the compiler do that makes it unaccessible to other classes?

Not much. The compiler doesn't protect against access to the data. It protects against access to the name of the data. For instance:

```
void foo(class bar&, int&);

class bar {
  int i = 0;
public:
  void baz() {
    foo(*this, i);
  }
};

void foo(class bar& b, int& i) {
  //b.i = 42; // This is an error. b.i is private

  i = 42; // This is okay, no matter what the local i refers to
}
```

In the example above, `foo()` cannot access `b.i` by name, because it's a private data member. But it can still modify it if it obtains a reference by other means. The member function `baz()` which has access to that name, binds it to the reference that `foo()` accepts. Thus allowing for its modification from outside the class's scope.